# Error: Call to a possibly undefined method

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the simplest code ever. Main class:

```
package 
{
import field.Field;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        var field:Field = new Field();
        addChild(field);
        field.test();
    }
}
}
```

and a Field class:

```
package field 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Field extends Sprite 
{

    public function Field() 
    {
        super();

    }

    public function test():void
    {

    }

}
}
```

**test** method is presented.
But when I try to compile I get this:
`Main.as(26): col: 10 Error: Call to a possibly undefined method test.
field.test();`

How could this be happening?

Comment: Have you imported the class?

Comment: Are sure that your class Field is in package field?

Comment: Yes, completely sure :/

Comment: Where are the package { } lines? Can you paste the entire files?

Comment: is `Field.as` in a directory `field`?

Comment: @Pimgd yes it is http://prntscr.com/5yxl8y

Comment: Class "Field", package "field", variable "field", with that naming you are just looking for trouble. Give your variable a different name.

Comment: Yes, my question has been answered right now. Never actually had this issue when variable name conflicts with package name. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`field` is your package, that's why you can not do `field.test()`. So you have to choose another name of your `Field` instance. You can do like this :

```
var _field:Field = new Field();
addChild(_field);
_field.test();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I'm very grateful! As usual it was the silliest thing. Thanks.